# RxJS observables and generic types for Angular2(Typescript) http wrapper

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

Today I encountered the following problem while trying to implement an abstract http service. This service should be base to extend for all other http services.

The implementation is following so far, skipping other methods for ilustration:

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class HttpWrapper<T> {

  private options: RequestOptions;

  constructor(private http: Http, private endpointUrl: string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  }

  public getAll(): Observable<T[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.endpointUrl, this.options)
      .map(this.extractAll)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  abstract handleError(error: any):Observable<Response>;

  abstract extractOne(res: Response):T;

  abstract extractAll(res: Response):T[];
}
```

Now if i want to use the abstract HttpWrapper i do the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class BlastReportService extends  HttpWrapper<Item> {

  constructor(http: Http) {
    super(http,'/api/items');
  }


  handleError(error: any):Observable<Response>{
    //Handling error
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }

  extractAll(res: Response):Item[]{
    let body = res.json();

    let formatedBody = body.map((item: Item) => {
      item = new Item(item);
      return blastReport;
    });

    return formatedBody || [{}];
  }
}
```

But doing this I get following compilation error:

```
Type 'Observable<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T[]>'.
  Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
    Property 'find' is missing in type 'Response'.
```

I can't wrap my head around this because the method extractAll clearly returns Item[] and is used while mapping the results returned from the server.

I decided to implement this abstract HttpWrapper "to stay DRY". I'm not sure if it's the best way to do so.

Comment: extractAll returns Item[], but your class is supposed to be a HttpWrapper<BlastReport>. So it's supposed to return a BlastReport[]. It's also unclear where this error message comes from. Please post the complete and exact error.

Comment: Also, your method is supposed to return an Observable<T[]>, but handleError returns an Observable<Response>.

Comment: Sorry about that blastReport, that shouldn't be in the question. Editing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem here is that `handleError()` returns an `Observable<Reponse>`, and therefore cannot be the return value of `getAll()` which expects an `Observable<T[]>`

Changing the return type of handleError to `Observable<T[]>` should fix the issue.

In `HttpWrapper`

```
abstract handleError(error: any):Observable<T[]>
```

In `BlastReportService`

```
handleError(error: any): Observable<T[]> {
  return Observable.throw(error)
}
```

Comment: Hi Philippe Plantier, the issue was in deed in handleError return value. Thank you very much.

Comment: Honestly I feel bit ashamed to post such a stupid question.

Comment: T is not reconized in a Angular service do you have any ideas

Comment: You should create a new question for this problem, and post your code. But as a guess, I would say that your service is not generic ? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes